# Use Expression Web with ASP.Net MVC

Tags: asp.net, css, asp.net-mvc, expression-web

First of all my question is what's the best tool, for create a asp.net mvc style.

I believe that it's possible to create an asp.net style (css) with Expression Web, but my doubt is, for example, how to create a table's style (and also dynamic `<li>` or `<div>` style create with markup `<% ... %>`), if the data are not visible.

There're methods to allow that?

thanks so much for replies

Alberto

Comment: What's wrong with the built in Visual Studio tools?

Comment: I don't know, you believe that it's enough to use Visual Studio's tools to create the styles?

Comment: You're going to have to learn how to write HTML, and not rely on GUI designers.  MVC requires a much more direct knowledge of HTML and how it works, and you are just asking for trouble if you don't know it at a tag level.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Visual Studio tools are fine for creating CSS and mark-up. If you are starting a greenfield project consider using MVC 3 and Razor as the view mark-up is more terse. Also Visual Studio 2010 SP1 now supports HTML5.